# Windows Deployment Services Fails After Reboot [RPC Related]

Tags: windows-server-2008, deployment, wds

I have installed the Windows Deployment Service as a role on our main Domain Controller, which also has the File Services and DHCP Roles installed on it.

During a routine maintenance update for Windows Updates, our machine (A VM) was restarted, but the Windows Deployment Service did not start up.

After some digging through the event log, I found that the error was caused by not being able to properly initialize a RPC server on port 5040 for our machine. Further looking into the event log shows that the RPC error is because of a duplicate endpoint. Searching for this issue hasn't turned anything up, and because our domain controller is in production I'm hesitant to restart the machine, which I figure would just clear up the RPC issues.

For the time being, I've set the WDS service to a delayed start, and the permissions on the Domain Controller are appropriate with cross checking Technet and other forums. DHCP Option 60 and 67 are enabled as recommended too, and were initially enabled.

Nothing has changed in our company's machine image. If all else fails I can just deploy via USB.

---

The service will not start manually. Here are the 3 separate Event Logs for the attempt:

The Windows Deployment Services Server service terminated with service-specific error The endpoint is a duplicate..

Event ID 7024

---

An error occurred while trying to start the Windows Deployment Services server.

Error Information: 0x6CC

Event ID 257

---

An error occurred while trying to initialize the RPC server on port 5040.

Error Information: 0x6CC

Event ID 1024

Comment: `I have installed the Windows Deployment Service as a role on our main Domain Controller` wat

Comment: In Server 2008 R2 you can add roles for your server. Windows Deployment Services is one of these roles. The server that I installed the role on also happens to be a domain controller.

Comment: Yes, I know you can. Domain controllers are normally expected to be just domain controllers.

Comment: Windows Firewall woes?

Comment: Unfortunately due to how my company doesn't wish to pay for an appropriate IT infrastructure, that is what I have to work with.

Comment: I will never understand how short-sighted decisions like that are thought to be *good* for the business. Let me ask you this.. How long have you spent on this problem so far?

Comment: About an hour. I was hired in to help their 1 man IT team restructure their management web of 750 machines.

I figured setting up a deployment server would help speed along the process while I build the company a ticket queue and a documentation wiki, as none of the above existed for this company for the past 8 years.

Comment: So the service fails to start when Windows loads, but when you come to start the service manually it starts fine? Can you paste the whole event log error in please?

Comment: Added to original question.

Comment: Please paste the errors into the question, properly formatted. It's really hard to read when it's inlined in a comment.

Comment: @user226513 I don't know the specs of this physical server, can you virtualize at all?

Comment: The server is virtualized. We're running Vmware's Hypersphere 5 on an HP Proliant Gen 8 machine. The VM has 32GB of ram and 8 cores.

That part was fun figuring out as our IT Manager didn't even know we were running Hypersphere.

Comment: Ok right so WDS and DHCP on same Server and WDS uses port 67. Port 67 is used by DHCP so you will need to go in to Windows Deployment Servers, right click your Server, Properties, DHCP Tab, tick to Not listen on port 67. You should find this Reg is changed to 0 HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\WDSServer\Providers\WDSPXE\UseDhcpPorts Restart and it should be sorted. The port 5040 is a red herring...

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the option "Do not listen on DHCP ports"?

Also did you check the box that says: Configure DHCP options to indecate that this is a DHCP server?

All of these options are in WDS server properties under:DHCP

That is what worked for me.

Comment: Sorry I did not read the comments. The same answer is in there... :-P